# Passing Classes as parameter to Windows Azure Cloud Service

Tags: vb.net, class, azure

I am writing an application in vb.net, to send data to an API in a cloud service hosted in Azure. Is there any benefit / harm in wrapping the data up in a class before sending it, as opposed to parameterised data. is the data still vulnerable to being stolen in transit. How could I protect that data?

Comment: This is a very very vague question! You really need to add some details about what it is you're trying to do, what sort of 'cloud service' you're connecting to. This question is impossible to answer in its current state. I am voting to close this question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm connecting to an Azure Cloud Service. The Cloud Service will act as a tier to get and return data from an Azure SQL Database. 

I was thinking of passing a Class as a parameter, then manipulate the Class in the Function, however, I was wondering whether the Class I am passing as a parameter would be vulnerable to being read (i.e the Properties etc) by somebody in the middle (my security knowledge is 0, hence why I'm asking and why it is quite vague because, honestly, I'm not entirely sure what i'm talking about...)

Comment: This might be a question that would be better asked at [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) as it isn't really a programming question -  but if you are sending data over the internet in clear text (not encrypted, not over SSL) then it is at risk of being stolen in transit.

Comment: I've edited your question a little, if you think there is anything missing, click on the click on the edit link and you can add or amend (or remove my edit completely) - I'm still not sure it is a good fit for SO, but it *might* stop it being closed.

Comment: @MichaelB Thank you, much better, sounds more like what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference whether you collect your data into a single class or send each bit as a single parameter over the wire your relevant information can still be extracted very easily.

If you are sending sensitive data over the internet you need to protect it in someway. You should at the very least make sure that you are connecting over an SSL connection. So you would need to purchase a certificate for your domain name and add it to Azure.

You also want to make sure that the API is using authentication, ideally written by someone who understands the implications of authentication design decisions (it is often surprisingly counter-intuitive)

If the data is particularly sensitive you should encrypt it with your own key before sending it and let the receiving server decrypt and process it if needs be, or if possible only store the encrypted data and decrypt on the client when you receive it again.

The most important thing though is to spend time researching, computer security is a big topic, having unsecured data can become an easy target for hackers and those looking to ransom your data.

An exceptionally good place to start is https://security.stackexchange.com/ there are some hugely knowledgable people there. (but you probably want to understand a little of what you're talking about before asking questions - inf security people aren't known for their helpful natures ;) )